# OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'Unable to locate element'

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find and click on an element using the pages xpath.
When I click on the specific element and inspect it using firebug the path never works and does not seem to be found even though firebug is able to find both the relative path and the absolute path?

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   driver.FindElement(By.XPath(
            "html/body/div[5]/div/div[103]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/img[2]")).Click();
```

and here is the relative path that firebug identifies

```
  .//*[@id='16']/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/img[2]


  <img class="Qv_CellIcon_right Qv_ULC" alt="" style="cursor: pointer; max-width: 202px; max-height: 16px;" src="/QvAjaxZfc/QvsViewClient.aspx?datamode=binary&name=ULC&host=QVS%40fuzionpulse-tst&slot=&public=only&xrfkey=nX73wyD2jq281aHj"/>
```

Comment: Can you provide sample HTML please?

Comment: sorry about that I added the html of what I'm trying to select

Comment: `//img[contains(@class, 'Qv_ULC')]` or `//*[@id='16']//img[contains(@class, 'Qv-ULC')]`? It's hard to tell for sure without seeing more of the `html` to see what's needed to uniquely identify the element.

Answer (score 0):

Extremely verbose XPaths run the risk of not being located, because of how exact the HTML has to be structured in order to "match".

Looking at the sample XPath/HTML you've provided, I see an `id` located in a parent element and class attributes in the `<img>`, which I would use to construct a more simplified XPath:

```
//*[@id='16']//img[@class='Qv_CellIcon_right Qv_ULC']
```

Explanation:

- `//*[@id='16']` - Select first matching node, where `id` equals `'16'`
- `//img[@class='Qv_CellIcon_right Qv_ULC']` - Select first matching `<img>`, where `class` attributes equals `'Qv_CellIcon_right Qv_ULC'`

Comment: hmmm it still appears to be unable to locate the element.

Comment: I based my answer from the (working?) XPath and the limited HTML you've provided. Are you still receiving a `NoSuchElementException` or is it a different error?

Comment: yes I get the error OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'Unable to locate element: //*[@id='16']//img[@class='Qv_CellIcon_right Qv_ULC']' That was the firepath xpath I got from the page is there a way to get a more specific customized xpath generated using a tool?

Comment: It would be more beneficial to learn how to create XPaths from scratch, I dislike the use of tools for this. For example, what if you add a new `<div>` somewhere? If you rely on Firebug, you'll potentially need to re-generate all the XPaths in your Selenium scripts. If you keep your XPaths more "generic" as in my example, you may not need to update your scripts as much.

Comment: do you have any good tutorials or examples on how to create XPaths from scrath?

Comment: Reading up on the [xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xpath) tag on StackOverflow really helped me learn by example, I suggest that. I frequently use [this](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) as a reference as well. Just play around with it, you'll get the hang of it :)